# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, list, indexing, typeerror

I've got two lists that I want to merge into a single array and finally put it in a csv file.

How I can avoid this error :

```py
def fill_csv(self, array_urls, array_dates, csv_file_path):
    result_array = []
    array_length = str(len(array_dates))

    # We fill the CSV file
    file = open(csv_file_path, "w")
    csv_file = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';', lineterminator='\n')

    # We merge the two arrays in one

    for i in array_length:
        result_array[i][0].append(array_urls[i])
        result_array[i][1].append(array_dates[i])
        i += 1

    csv_file.writerows(result_array)
```

And got :

```
  File "C:\Users\--\gcscan.py", line 63, in fill_csv
    result_array[i][0].append(array_urls[i])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

How can my count work ?

Comment: You explicitly make `array_length` a string, so `i` is a character not a number...

Comment: Ooops, I wasn't look the right way....thank you !!

Comment: this happened to me when I thought I was parsing `{thisthing}` when actually I was parsing `[{thisthing}]`; e.g., I was trying to deal with a dictionary but actually I was dealing with a list. Dynamic typing ftw.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

First, `array_length` should be an integer and not a string:

```
array_length = len(array_dates)
```

Second, your `for` loop should be constructed using `range`:

```
for i in range(array_length):  # Use `xrange` for python 2.
```

Third, `i` will increment automatically, so delete the following line:

```
i += 1
```

---

Note, one could also just `zip` the two lists given that they have the same length:

```
import csv

dates = ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03']
urls = ['www.abc.com', 'www.cnn.com', 'www.nbc.com']

csv_file_patch = '/path/to/filename.csv'

with open(csv_file_patch, 'w') as fout:
    csv_file = csv.writer(fout, delimiter=';', lineterminator='\n')
    result_array = zip(dates, urls)
    csv_file.writerows(result_array)
```

Comment: There is no magic: `i` is an element of the list returned by range (or sequence in python 3). Oh, BTW: they're all lists, not arrays.

Answer (score 17):

Follow up on Abdeali Chandanwala [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56321135/10029809) above (couldn't comment because rep<50)  -

TL;DR: I was trying to iterate through a list of dictionaries incorrectly by focusing to iterate over the keys in the dictionary but instead had to iterate over the dictionaries themselves!

---

I came across the same error while having a structure like this:

```
{
   "Data":[
      {
         "RoomCode":"10",
         "Name":"Rohit",
         "Email":"rohit@123.com"
      },
      {
         "RoomCode":"20"
         "Name":"Karan",
         "Email":"karan@123.com"
      }
   ]
}
```

And I was trying to append the names in a list like this-

[image: Same error received]

Fixed it by-

[image: Fixed the error]

Answer (score 13):

I had same error and the mistake was that I had added list and dictionary into the same list (object) and when was iterating over the list of dictionaries and hit a list type object then I would get this error since I was trying to access keys within each dictionary.

I had to made sure that I only added dictionary objects to that list

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was trying to change the value of a `dict` key but since my `dict` was there in a for loop and was getting changed to type `list` i was getting the same error.

```
for value in source_list:
    my_dict['my_key']=some_val
    dict=list(mydict)
    exctraction0 = dict[0]
```

i resolved it by making sure the type of `dict` remains the same by making a `deepcopy` and `re-initializing` after every `iteration`(that is what the use-case was all about).

```
copy_dict = copy.deepcopy(my_dict)
for value in source_list:
    my_dict =copy.deepcopy(copy_dict)
    my_dict['my_key']=some_val
    dict=list(mydict)
    exctraction0 = dict[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

As the message says, this error occurs when a string is used to index a list. *Most* of the cases leading to this error can be summarized in the following cases.

#### 1. A list is used as if it were a dictionary

##### 1.1. Index a list as if it was a dictionary

This case commonly occurs when a json object is converted into a Python object but there's a dictionary nested inside a list. It is especially annoying (and easy to overlook) if the list has a single dictionary inside it. In the example below, the value under the `'summary'` key is a list than contains a single dictionary. So if one tries to get the home score using `json['summary']['home_score']`, it will show an error.

```py
json = {
    "teams": {"home": "BOS", "away": "MIA"},
    "summary": [
        {"home_score": 0, "away_score": 0}
    ]
}

json['summary']['home_score']               # <---- TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
json['summary'][0]['home_score']            # <---- OK (returns the first item)
#              ^^^   <---- index the list here
[d['home_score'] for d in json['summary']]  # <---- OK (returns a list)
```

When making a http request, an API call, etc. the outcome is usually very nested and it's not very obvious how to handle that data but with a simple debugging step such as printing the type, length etc. of the data usually shows how to handle it.

```py
print(type(json['summary']))                # <class 'list'>    <---- check the data type
print(len(json['summary']))                 #                   <---- check length of data
print(type(json['summary'][0]))             # <class 'dict'>    <---- check type of item
```

##### 1.2. Assign values to a list as if it were a dictionary

Another common mistake is to initialize a list but try to assign values to it using a key. The initialization probably happened dynamically and it's not clear later on that it's in fact a list. For example, in the following case, `d` is initialized as a list but there's an attempt to add a key-value pair to it. A solution is to initialize an empty dict `{}` instead of `[]`.

```py
d = []
d['key'] = 1                                # <---- TypeError


d = {}
d['key'] = 1                                # <---- OK
```

##### 1.3. A pandas dataframe is accidentally changed into a list

A common way to change column labels of a pandas dataframe is to directly assign a list of strings intended to be the new labels to `pd.DataFrame.columns` attribute. If it's assigned to `pd.DataFrame` instead, the entire dataframe gets replaced by a list and it's not possible to access a column by label anymore.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([range(4), range(4)])
df = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
df['A']                                     # <---- TypeError


df = pd.DataFrame([range(4), range(4)])
df.columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
# ^^^^^^^^  <---- assign column labels here
df['A']                                     # <---- OK
```

#### 2. A string is used as if it were an integer

##### 2.1. Index a list using an `input()`

A very common mistake is when one tries to index a list using a value from a user input. Because `input()` returns a string, it has to be converted into an integer before being used to index a list.

```py
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c']
index = input()

lst[index]                                  # <---- TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
lst[int(index)]                             # <---- OK
```

##### 2.2. Using a list of strings to index a list

Another common mistake is to loop over a list and use a list item to index a list. Python's `for` is similar to Perl's `foreach` in the sense that the loop is over a collection of items. Since the list is already being iterated over, there's no need to index it again, so a solution is to use the item directly for whatever operation that needs to be done with it. Or perhaps loop over a `range` object that constructed using the length of the list.

```py
lst = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'd']

lst['a']                                    # <---- TypeError
lst[lst.index('a')]                         # <---- OK
```

This error probably happens much more often in a loop where `lst` was created dynamically.

```py
for i in lst:
    if lst[i] == 'b':                       # <---- TypeError
        pass

for i in lst:
    if i == 'b':                            # <---- OK
        pass
    
for i in range(len(lst)):                   # <---- OK
    if lst[i] == 'b':
        pass
```

N.B. This is OP's case. A for-loop over a string uses a string to index a list. The solution is to loop over a range object.

Answer (score 1):

I received this error overloading a function in python where one function wrapped another:

```
def getsomething(build_datastruct_inputs : list[str]) -> int:
      # builds datastruct and calls getsomething
      return getsomething(buildit(build_datastruct_inputs))

def getsomething(datastruct : list[int]) -> int:
      # code
      # received this error on first use of 'datastruct'
```

Fix was to not overload and use unique method name.

```
def getsomething_build(build_datastruct_inputs : list[str]) -> int:
      # builds datastruct and calls getsomething
      return getsomething_ds(buildit(build_datastruct_inputs))

def getsomething_ds(datastruct : list[int]) -> int:
      # code
      # works fine again regardless of whether invoked directly/indirectly
```

Another fix could be to use python multipledispatch package which will let you overload and figures this out for you.

Was a bit confusing because where the error was occuring (nor message) corresponded to what cause was.  I thought I had seen that python supported overloading natively but now I've learned it's implementation requires more work from the user.

Answer (score 0):

I got here from Google, with my error happening on code such as

```
a = ["b"]
del a["b"]
```

error:

```
del a["b"]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

This happens because deleting from a list can only take indices in the list or slices.

---

Instead, one should use

```
a.remove("b")
```

---

Notice this is now an `o(n)` operation.