# Python3 TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: string, list, python-3.x, int, typeerror

i have the task to get the String `'AAAABBBCCDAABBB'` into a list like this: `['A','B','C','D','A','B']`

I am working on this for 2 hours now, and i can't get the solution. This is my code so far:

```
list = []

string = 'AAAABBBCCDAABBB'

i = 1

for i in string:
    list.append(i)

print(list)

for element in list:
    if list[element] == list[element-1]:
        list.remove(list[element])

print(list)
```

I am a newbie to programming, and the error "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str" always shows up...

I already changed the comparison

```
if list[element] == list[element-1]
```

to

```
if list[element] is list[element-1]
```

But the error stays the same. I already googled a few times, but there were always lists which didn't need the string-format, but i need it (am i right?).

Thank you for helping!
*NoAbL*

Comment: element is a `string`, indexes of an iterable must be numbers not strings

Comment: In `element in list`, `element` is a list element, not a list index. If you want the index, use `for index in range(len(list))` or `for index,element in enumerate(list)`.

Comment: As danidee said, you are grabbing the actual item in the list not the index of the item when you say for element in list. Therefore you can't do list[element] afterwards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32554527/typeerror-list-indices-must-be-integers-or-slices-not-str)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all don't name your variables after built in python statements or data structures like `list`, `tuple` or even the name of a module you import, this also applies to files. for example naming your file `socket.py` and importing the `socket` module is definitely going to lead to an error (I'll leave you to try that out by yourself)

in your code `element` is a string, indexes of an iterable must be numbers not strings, so you can tell python

give me the item at position 2.

but right now you're trying to say give me the item at position `A` and that's not even valid in English, talk-less of a programming language.

you should use the `enumerate` function if you want to get indexes of an iterable as you loop through it or you could just do

```
for i in range(len(list))
```

and loop through the range of the length of the list, you don't really need the elements anyway.

Here is a simpler approach to what you want to do

```
s = string = 'AAAABBBCCDAABBB'

ls = []

for i in s:
    if ls:
        if i != ls[-1]:
            ls.append(i)
    else:
        ls.append(i)

print(ls)
```

Answer (score 3):

It is a different approach, but your problem can be solved using **[`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)** as follows:

```
from itertools import groupby

string = 'AAAABBBCCDAABBB'
answer = [group[0] for group in groupby(string)]
print(answer)
```

**Output**

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B']
```

According to the documentation, `groupby`:

> Make an iterator that returns consecutive keys and groups from the iterable

In my example we use a list comprehension to iterate over the consecutive keys and groups, and use the index `0` to extract just the key.

Comment: Although this doesn't address the OP's problems with indexing this, I think, is the best way to do it.

Comment: Yes - it is a slightly different approach, but I thought it was worthwhile adding as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code:

```
list = []

string = 'AAAABBBCCDAABBB'

# remove the duplicate character before append to list
prev = ''
for char in string:
    if char == prev:
        pass
    else:
        list.append(char)
        prev = char
print(list)
```

**Output:**

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B']
```

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, `element` is the string. You want to have the *index*.

Try `for i, element in enumerate(list)`.

EDIT: `i` will now be the index of the `element` you're currently iterating through.

Comment: The error is away now, but now the list is `['A','B','C','D','A','A','B','B','B']`