# How to extract a Data from Riot Games API?

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests

I am still a beginner and have just started with Python.
I try to get the tier and rank of a player with the Riot Games(only EUW) API via JSON, but I get a Exception:

```
print (responseJSON2[ID][0]['tier'])

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I dont know what I have to change, maybe someone can help me :)
Code:

```
import requests

def requestSummonerData(summonerName, APIKey):

    URL = "https://euw1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by-name/" + summonerName + "?api_key=" + APIKey
    print (URL)
    response = requests.get(URL)
    return response.json()

def requestRankedData(ID, APIKey):
    URL= "https://euw1.api.riotgames.com/lol/league/v3/positions/by-summoner/"+ID+"?api_key="+APIKey
    print (URL)
    response = requests.get(URL)
    return response.json()


def main():

    summonerName = (str)(input('Type your Summoner Name here: '))
    APIKey = (str)(input('Copy and paste your API Key here: '))
    responseJSON  = requestSummonerData(summonerName, APIKey)

    print(responseJSON)
    ID = responseJSON ['id']
    ID = str(ID)
    print (ID)
    responseJSON2 = requestRankedData(ID, APIKey)
    print (responseJSON2[ID][0]['tier'])
    print (responseJSON2[ID][0]['entries'][0]['rank'])
    print (responseJSON2[ID][0]['entries'][0]['leaguePoints'])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Looks like a duplicate here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32554527/typeerror-list-indices-must-be-integers-or-slices-not-str

Answer (score 0):

`responseJSON2` is a `list`. A list has indexes (0, 1, 2, ...).

You need to use an int for your list:

```
ID = str(ID)
```

is wrong, you need to have an int there!

try with

```
ID = int(ID)
```

And you can convert back in string:

```
def requestRankedData(ID, APIKey):
    URL= "https://euw1.api.riotgames.com/lol/league/v3/positions/by-summoner/"+str(ID)+"?api_key="+APIKey
    print (URL)
    response = requests.get(URL)
    return response.json()
```

You need to find the index matching your ID in your response:

```
responseJSON2 = requestRankedData(ID, APIKey)
ID_idx = responseJSON2.index(str(ID))
print (responseJSON2[ID_idx][0]['tier'])
print (responseJSON2[ID_idx][0]['entries'][0]['rank'])
print (responseJSON2[ID_idx][0]['entries'][0]['leaguePoints'])
```

Comment: i try it, but now i get a exception by the URL. It says that the ID must be a str.                                                                                                   
                                                                                                          
        URL= "https://euw1.api.riotgames.com/lol/league/v3/positions/by-summoner/"+ID+"?api_key="+APIKey

TypeError: must be str, not int

Comment: I have updated the answer, you just need to convert it back when building your string.

Comment: I changed it and now this is coming: print (responseJSON2[ID][0]['tier'])

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: It's because your ID is not your index. You need to first look for the index that match your ID, then use this index. As a side note, as you are requesting data for a specific ID, I doubt that you have data for more than one ID in your response.

Answer (score 0):

There is my code :

```
from riotwatcher import LolWatcher()

region = str(input("Your region : ")) #If you only need EUW, just do region = "euw1"
summonerName = str(input("Your summonername : ")) #Asking for the user's summoner name
watcher = LolWatcher(api_key="your_api_key")
summonner = watcher.summoner.by_name(region=region, summoner_name=pseudo) #Getting account informations, you can print(summoner) to see what it gives
rank = watcher.league.by_summoner(region=region, encrypted_summoner_id=summonner["id"]) #User ranks using his id in summoner

tier = rank[0]["tier"]
ranklol = rank[0]["rank"]
lp = rank[0]["leaguePoints"]

print(f"{tier} {ranklol} {lp} LP")
```

It should be ok, I don't know why are you working with the link, use the API features, it's way more easier. Hope I helped you.