# access to json values using python

Tags: mysql, json, python-3.x

I have my JSON file:

```
[
   {
      "order_":{
         "id":"B2B78502",
         "status_order_id":5,
         "status_order_name":"Sent",
         "customer_id":256,
         "order_products":[
            {
               "order_product":{
                  "id":83630,
                  "order_id":79288,
                  "product_id":13519,
                  "quantity":"1.0",
                  "price":"72.44",
                  "addressbook_":{
                     "name":"user user",
                     "address":"adress",
                     "city":"THIENNES",
                     "country":"FR",
                     "postal_code":"59189",
                     "phone":"000000000"
                  },
                  "product_name":"product",
                  "product_code":"20159"
               }
            }
         ],
         "customer_email":"user@gmail.com",
         "customer_company":"SARL"
      }
   }
]
```

I want to insert data into a MySQL table, but I can not access all the values

here is my code:

```
json_obj = r.json()

for ord in json_obj:
    print("id:", ord["order"]["id"])
    print("order_produvt_id:", ord["order"]["order_products"]"order_product"]["id"])
    print('---')
```

I want to access all the data I want to access all the data but I get this error :

```
  id: B2B78588
    print("order_product_id:", ord["order"]["order_products"]["order_product"]["id"])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: That's not JSON.

Comment: and check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32554527/typeerror-list-indices-must-be-integers-or-slices-not-str).

Comment: it's a JSON recover from an API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In side "order_products", you have an *array*, indicated by these braces: [ ].

You need to access arrays with Integers, like the error tells you.

```
ord["order"]["order_products"][0]["order_product"]["id"]
```

The above example should work.

Comment: yes you are right thank you, I did not pay attention that it is an array, I tried your code, I get this error: KeyError: 'id'

Comment: Edited my answer. I missed that "id" was in the "order_product" object