# Creating a dictionary from a json list of arrays

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm trying to create a dictionary of specific key values from a list of dictionaries. I believe my code is not flattening out the dictionaries when i put in  chunkdata.extend(pythondict[0][1][2], chunkdata will return with the whole 1st 2nd and 3rd dictionaries where i want something like the "name" key pair for all the dictionaries that return in the response.

```
chunkdata = []
for chunk in chunklist:
    url3 = "some URL"

    headers = {'accept': 'application/json',


    response = requests.request("GET", url3, headers=headers)
    time.sleep(5)
    print(response.text)
    pythondict = json.loads(response.text)
    print(pythondict)

    chunkdata.extend(pythondict['name']['age']['date']
```

---

pythondict output

[{'data': {'name': 'jon', 'age': '30', 'date': '2020-01-05', 'time': '1', 'color': 'blue'}, {'data': {'name': 'phil', 'age': '33', 'date': '2020-01-05', 'time': '1', 'color': 'blue'}, {'data': {'name': 'ted', 'age': '25', 'date': '2020-01-05', 'time':'1', 'color': 'blue'}]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File line 84, in <module>
    chunkdata.extend(pythondict['name']['age']['date']
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: What is the output of `print(pythondict)`?

Comment: Please, check ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: print(pythondict) output is a list of dictionaries that was converted from the raw json in response.text

Comment: It would be nice if we could see those dictionaries spring.... Not  very useful if we are just guessing because you aren't showing enough to make a minimal  complete example...

Comment: One of `['name']['age']['date']` is a list not a dictionary. Beyond that, no  one can give you a better answer  with your question as it sits.

Comment: If print(pythondict) output is a list of dictionaries, then you'd need to use integer indexes to access its elements (or just iterate through using something like `a_dict for a_dict in a_list`).

Comment: Sorry pythondict output added above. I condensed it down some because there are 50 around keys and 100s of dictionaries.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32554527/typeerror-list-indices-must-be-integers-or-slices-not-str)

Answer (score 0):

Use `requests.json()` for parsing. It is more reliable and accurate.

Note: Response header MUST contain `Content-Type: application/json` in the header in order for `.json()` method to work

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the json format you get is not right here. I was not able to make out the necessity of the 'data:' prior to each element.
It would be better to modify it in the following form:

python_dict=[{'name': 'jon', 'age': '30', 'date': '2020-01-05', 'time': '1', 'color': 'blue'}, {'name': 'phil', 'age': '33', 'date': '2020-01-05', 'time': '1', 'color': 'blue'}, {'name': 'ted', 'age': '25', 'date': '2020-01-05', 'time':'1', 'color': 'blue'}]

Modify the relevant part of the code as follows:

```
chunkdata=[]
for x in range(len(python_dict)):
    temp_list=[python_dict[x]['name'],python_dict[x]['age'],python_dict[x]['date'],python_dict[x]['time'],python_dict[x]['color']]
    chunkdata.append(temp_list)
print(chunkdata)
```

chunkdata will be a list of lists that you can keep appending into. The output for chunkdata is as follows:

> [['jon', '30', '2020-01-05', '1', 'blue'], ['phil', '33',
>   '2020-01-05', '1', 'blue'], ['ted', '25', '2020-01-05', '1', 'blue']]