# Accessing keys and values within them in a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary in python and I want to extract some values based on the keys I have. For each row, I have 3 keys (arrival, dep, code) and sometimes all of them appear but sometimes only 1 or 2 of them exist. I want for each row, if a key exists, to take the value otherwise to just put not available or 0. Here is my example data:

**Example data**

```
dict_items([('arrival', {'week': 3, 'timing': '15:30'}), ('code', '123')])

dict_items([('dep', {'week': 3, 'timing': '10:15'}), ('code', '456')])

dict_items([('arrival', {'week': 4, 'timing': '22:30'}), ('dep', {'week': '', 'timing': ''}), ('code', '567')])            

dict_items([('dep', {'week': 7, 'timing': '23:00'})
```

**Output to include 5 lists**

```
arrival_week_list []

arrival_timing_list []

dep_week_list []

dep_timing_list []

code []
```

This is my code so far I have tried it initially to just get the week for 'arrival' (there is also week within 'dep')

```
for i in list:
    for row in i:
        try:
            arrival_week_list.append(i['week'])
        except KeyError:
                arrival_week_list.append(np.nan)
        print(arrival_week_list)
```

But I got an error: **TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str**

Comment: `row` is a `list` not a `dict`

Comment: I didnt include the top line of my loop, in the first iteration I access the dictionary and then I get confused on how to proceed

Comment: It looks to me like you want to define a class. Trying to do this with dicts is going to be really annoying and unmaintainable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32554527/typeerror-list-indices-must-be-integers-or-slices-not-str)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to select in which list you want to add the values base on the key from the `dict`, here is my approach:

```
data = {
    'arrival': {
        'week': [],
        'timing': [],
    },
    'dep': {
        'week': [],
        'timing': [],
    },
    'code': []
}

for my_dict in my_list:
    for key, values in my_dict.items():
        if isinstance(values, dict):
            for k, v in values.items():
                data[key][k].append(v)
        else:
            data[key].append(values)

arrival_week_list = data['arrival']['week']

arrival_timing_list = data['arrival']['timing']

dep_week_list = data['dep']['week']

dep_timing_list = data['dep']['timing']

code = data['code']
print(arrival_week_list)
print(arrival_timing_list)
print(dep_week_list)
print(dep_timing_list)
print(code)
```

**output:**

```
[3, 4]
['15:30', '22:30']
[3, '', 7]
['10:15', '', '23:00']
['123', '456', '567']
```

Comment: thank you for your input, I am having a difficulty understanding what "data" stands for. I have only one list that contains multiple dictionaries in it, not multiple lists.

Comment: data is an intermediary  data structure to hold in a simple way your information, you can use data instead of the lists if you want

Comment: I do not have that data component, and I am confused a bit, I dont know if you can provide some alternative. Initially I had a list that contains the dictionaries and when I loop through the list I do not have a dictionary name

Answer (score 1):

The error is coming from row['week'].

Your dictionary is a list such as

```
[('arrival', {'week': 3, 'timing': '15:30'}), ('code', '123')]
```

What you likely want to do, is

```
a = [('arrival', {'week': 3, 'timing': '15:30'}), ('code', '123')]
a[0][1]['week']
3
```

to access 3 for example

a[0] gives you a tuple ('arrival, {'week': 3, 'timing': '15:30'}) for example, 
a[0][1] gets to the dictionary.

Comment: I do not fully get it sorry, I have a list and within it, a dictionary how do I access the values of the dictionary based on the keys? I get your example kind of but not completely

Comment: essentially how do i do it in a loop?