# Iterating through a dictionary: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I'm new to Python trying to build a web scraper with Scrapy and I am getting a lot of non-printing and blank spaces in the results. I'm attempting to iterate through a dictionary with a for loop where the values are lists, then run the .strip() method to get rid of all the non-printing characters. Only now I this error instead, "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str". I know I must be reaching into the object wrong, but after a few days of sifting through docs and similar exceptions I haven't found a way to resolve it yet.

The code I'm using is:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from ..items import JobcollectorItem
from ..AutoCrawler import searchIndeed


class IndeedSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'indeed'
    page_number = 2
    start_urls = [searchIndeed.current_page_url]

    def parse(self, response):
        items = JobcollectorItem()

        position = response.css('.jobtitle::text').extract()
        company = response.css('span.company::text').extract()
        location = response.css('.location::text').extract()

        # print(position[0])

        items['position'] = position
        items['company'] = company
        items['location'] = location

        for key in items.keys():
            prestripped = items[key]
            for object in prestripped:
                object = object.strip('\n')
            items[key] = prestripped

        yield items
```

I'm using python 3.7.4. Any tips on simplifying the function to get rid of the nested for loops would also be appreciated. The code for the entire project can be found [here](https://github.com/dantehollo/jobcollector).

Thanks for the help!

Edit0:
The exception is thrown at line 27 reading:
"    prestripped = items[key][value]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Edit1:
The data structure is items{'key':[list_of_strings]} where the dictionary name is items, the keys are string and the key's value is a list, with each list element being a sting.

Edit2:
Updated the code to reflect Alex.Kh's answer. Also, here is an approximation of what is currently getting returned: {company: ['\nCompany Name', '\n', '\nCompany Name', '\n', '\n', '\n',], location: ['Some City, US', 'Some City, US'], position: [' ', '\n', '\nPosition Name', ' ', ' Position Name']}

Comment: Please always post a full error log wth line number and everything. It helps debug instead of guessing on which line error occurred.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32554527/typeerror-list-indices-must-be-integers-or-slices-not-str)

Comment: @AMC Not that I could see. I read through it already last week. I believe their issue was they didn't notice that they were casting len() to a string when they needed an integer. I know that I'm looking at a string, I don't know where that string is coming from.

Comment: @HollowDante As for simplifying your `for` loop, what about `for key, value in zip(items.keys(),items.values())`?

Comment: @Alex.Kh "AttributeError: key" on line 25, which is where the for loop is initiated. I'm still a novice at this, but it looks like it is colliding with something in Scrapy itself ("raise AttributeError(name)" from its 'item.py' file). I did not know that zip() was a thing. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to my comment, I think I know how to simplify and fix your code as well.

```
...
for key in items.keys():
   restripped = items[key]
   #BEWARE: a novice mistake here as object is just a copy
   for object in restripped: #assuming extract() returns a list
         object=object.strip() # will change a temporary copy
   items[key] = restripped
...
```

I am not sure why exactly you need a value in your loop, so you could also just say `for key in items.keys():`. You main mistake was probably accessing the dictionary incorrectly(`items[key][value]->items[key]` as `value` is an actually value that corresponds to that key).

**Edit**:I spotted a huge mistake from my part in the `for` loop. As it creates a copy, the statement `object=object.strip()` will not affect the actual list. Guess not using Python for a while does make you forget certain features

I will leave the incorrect solution a reminder both to me and others. The correct way to use the `strip()` method is as follows:

```
...
#correct solution
for key in items.keys():
   restripped = items[key]
   for i,object in enumerate(restripped):
         # alternatively: restripped[i]=restripped[i].strip()
         restripped[i]=object.strip()
   items[key] = restripped
...
```

Comment: Yeah, I know I'm accessing it wrong. However, when I leave [value] out I get this:    stripped = prestripped.strip()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'. 
So I go from looking at a string, which I need for .strip(), to looking at a list.

Comment: @HollowDante. I haven't directly worked with the framework you are using , but my answer is definitely going to help you in some way. I would probably look at the `extract()` method(for ex. in `position = response.css('.jobtitle::text').extract()`). I think it might be returning a list of objects, so you might have to iterate through them and strip each object. I will correct my initial post to show it

Comment: @HollowDante I also got rid of `values` part as it is not needed. Alternatively, I could have used `items.values()` as that's what you are actually interested in

Comment: I made an edit to my post to show what I believe is getting returned. I should have included that earlier, sorry.

Comment: @HollowDante If so, my answer should work for you. It will obtain the list of strings for each key , iterate through and strip each string

Comment: Updated the code and ran it. It doesn't throw an error anymore, but it also doesn't remove the white space. I'm going to assume that your solution worked and either I wasn't specific enough with my css selectors, or the site was made to be deliberately obtuse to web crawlers. I know a lot of sites get sniffy with them.

Comment: @HollowDante. Your `strip()` will not remove spaces in the text anyway as the argument is empty. By definition, *The strip() removes characters from both left and right based on the argument*. Only trailing whitespaces will be removed