# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-conversion, typeerror

I'm trying to write a program in Python3, which does the following:

- It inputs the number of the test cases
- It then inputs some numbers
- It splits the digits of the input numbers and checks, if the digits are the number's divisor or not. If yes, it will raise a counter by one.
- It finally has to print the number of existing divisors for every number in a separate line.

Here's my code for this:

```
t = int(input("Number of test cases:"))
numlist = []
for i in range(0, t):
    numstring = input()
    numlist.extend(list(numstring))
    for j in numlist:
        if int(numstring) % int(numlist[j]) == 0 and int(numlist[j]) != 0:
            cnt += 1
    numlist = []
print(cnt)
```

The problem is, that I face an error for the line where it's written `if int(numstring) % int(numlist[j]) == 0 and int(numlist[j]) != 0:` . The error says: `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str` , I don't know why this should occur, haven't I already converted the strings into int by putting an `int` in front of them?

**Any help, solution and tips are greatly appreciated!**

Comment: `numlist.extend(list(numstring))` will extend that list with the string contents of `numstring`. So you are iterating over a list like `['1', '2', '3', ...]` which aren't valid indices when you go to look up `numlist['1']`, for instance

Comment: Isn't there a solution for this then? @C.Nivs

Comment: I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32554527/7867968) answers this

Answer (score 1):

the typeError can be solved with the modification you find below. However, I believe there is a major logic issue in the way you are trying to solve this problem.

```
    t = int(input("Number of test cases:"))
    numlist = []
    cnt = 0
    for i in range(0, t):
        numstring = int(input()) # change 1
        numlist.append(numstring) # change 2
        for j in numlist:
            if int(numstring) % int(numlist[j]) == 0 and int(numlist[j]) != 0:
                cnt += 1
        numlist = []
   print(cnt)
```