# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str even after following other Answers

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I want to get an Tempmail from 1secmail.com via an python API request. For this goal I wrote this code:

```
import requests
import random
import string
import json

url = 'https://www.1secmail.com/api/v1/?action=getMessages&login=Demo&domain=1secmail.com'
r = requests.get(url)
raw = r.json()
print(raw["id"])
```

And the Response looks like this:

```
[{
"id": 69,
"from": "someone@example.com",
"subject": "Some subject",
"date": "2018-06-08 14:33:55"
}, {
"id": 68,
"from": "someoneelse@example.com",
"subject": "Other subject",
"date": "2018-06-08 14:40:55"
}]
```

I want to get the "id" so I can read the email in a later step, but everytime I try to get the id i get this error: "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

I tried some other [Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32554527/typeerror-list-indices-must-be-integers-or-slices-not-str) but without succsess.

Any Help is appreciated, and please keep in mind that I am not a native speaker so please dont be to hard on my spelling and grammar ;)

Comment: how are you trying to get the id?

Comment: The response you've posted is a list of two objects. The first id would be `raw[0]['id']` and the second would be `raw[1]['id']`.

Comment: *Which* `id` were you expecting to get with that expression?  There are two of them in your example data...  `raw[0]['id']` would get the first one, `raw[1]['id']` would get the second - or perhaps you need to loop over `raw`, in order to handle however many sub-objects (each with their own `id`) there might be.

Comment: " tried some other Answers but without succsess." Okay, so when you read that answer, in your own words, what did you decide is wrong with your own code? How did you change the code to fix the problem? What happened when you did that? In your own words, when you do `print(raw["id"])`, what exactly do you think should be printed? Why? When you saw the error message, `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`, did you *understand what that means*? Do you know what a `TypeError` is? Do you knowwhat a `list index` is? Do you understand why that index cannot be a `str`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That response is a list of elements (see the square brackets `[` and `]`). You can iterate on that list and print the id of each inner [`dict`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp) as follows.

```
l = r.json()
for e in l:
    print(e['id'])
```