# TypeError the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not TextIOWrapper and list indices must be integers or slices, not str when using json.load

Tags: python, json

So I'm trying to make a file searcher just to make it easier for myself regarding all the files with info I have, I've gotten to the part where it can extract the file but then

I've tried using json.loads() but get `TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not TextIOWrapper` and when I use json.load() I get `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

here is my code:

```
class fileSearcher:
    def __init__(self):
        self.directory = "my directory"
        self.word = str(input(f'Input the word you want to search for: '))
        if self.word != "":
            self.main()
        else:
            fileSearcher()

    def main(self):
        for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(self.directory):
            for file in files:
                filepath = subdir + os.sep + file
                for ft in ".zip":
                    if ft in filepath:
                        archive = ZipFile(filepath)
                        for file2 in archive.namelist():
                            if file2.__contains__("https"):
                                with ZipFile(filepath, 'r') as zip: 
                                    zip.extract(file2,os.getcwd())
                                f = open(file2)
                                data = json.load(open(file2))
                                for i in data['url']:
                                    if i.__contains__(self.word):
                                        with open("file", "w+")as f:
                                            f.write(f"{self.word}: {data['url']}")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    fileSearcher()
```

Comment: For a [mcve], you could remove the call to `input()` (why the explicit conversion to `str`, btw?) so we don't have to guess what input triggers the behaviour. Please, as a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do

```
for i in data:
    if self.word in i["url"]:
```

instead of `data['url']` check out [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32554527/typeerror-list-indices-must-be-integers-or-slices-not-str?rq=1) like this for a better answer and in this case you want to be using json.load()

The json.load() is used to read the JSON document from file and the json.loads() is used to convert the JSON String document into the Python dictionary.

Comment: thank you that appearantly was it xd

Answer (score 0):

The file2 should contains a `list` not a `dict` that's why.

In addition, you might have a bug in your code. You wrote:

```py
for ft in ".zip":
    if ft in filepath:
```

I think you wanted:

```py
if ".zip" in filepath
```

Also, to have a cleaner code, you can look at [Glob library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html)

Edit:

Same here:

```py
if i.__contains__(self.word):
```

You should not use `__contains__` because it's a dunder method.
you can do:

```py
if self.word in i:
```